# how to add new line before *****MSH in notepadd++ ( the * represent any numer, total 5 numbers )

Tags: notepad++

i want to add a new line before ( *****MSH ) the stars is any number, there is total 5 numbers before MSH.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is nothing else on those lines (as you didn't specify anything) and it is always exactly five numbers, you can use the regular expression `(\d{5}MSH)` as the text to look for an just replace it with `\r\n$0`.

As Toto pointed out you could also use `$0\r\n`. The difference would be whenever the newline character(s) would be added before or after your match. The result (assuming the file just contains those MSH lines) would be either an empty line at the start of the file or an empty line at the bottom of the file.

[image: Notepad++ regular expression]

Comment: In the capture, you should change the replacement by `\r\n$0`. Also, there're no needs to capture group as you aren't using it.

Comment: You're correct about the group. The other change would make it fit more closely but the OP never specified. It's the difference between having a blank line at the end or the start. I'll try to include an edit about it.

Comment: They said "i want to add a new line **before**"

Comment: I wasn't talking about the text but in the image you have linebreak **after** the group.