# How to insert two lines of text after every line?

Tags: notepad++

```
63888501
36346246
36026700
53846004
57910034
45585184
11389311
47389379
63389410
23392487
```

Output should be:

```
63888501 
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe 
notepad.exe one.txt
36346246
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
notepad.exe one.txt
36026700
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
notepad.exe one.txt
53846004
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
notepad.exe one.txt
57910034
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
notepad.exe one.txt
45585184
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
notepad.exe one.txt
11389311
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
notepad.exe one.txt
47389379
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
notepad.exe one.txt
63389410
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
notepad.exe one.txt
23392487
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe
notepad.exe one.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `$`
- Replace with: `\ntaskkill /f /im ffs.exe \nnotepad.exe one.txt`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
$       # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
\n                          # linefeed, you can use \r\n for windows files
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe     # literally
\n                          # linefeed, you can use \r\n for windows files
notepad.exe one.txt         # literally
```

**Result for given example:**

```
63888501
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe 
notepad.exe one.txt
36346246
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe 
notepad.exe one.txt
36026700
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe 
notepad.exe one.txt
53846004
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe 
notepad.exe one.txt
57910034
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe 
notepad.exe one.txt
45585184
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe 
notepad.exe one.txt
11389311
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe 
notepad.exe one.txt
47389379
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe 
notepad.exe one.txt
63389410
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe 
notepad.exe one.txt
23392487
taskkill /f /im ffs.exe 
notepad.exe one.txt
```

Comment: You don't need to check "Wrap around" if you just use an extended replace. Instead you would just search for `\n` or `\r\n`, doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: @Seth: True, but it's not really important.

Answer (score 1):

Search and Replace with the extended replace for `\r\n` and replace it with `\r\n<your text>`.

`\r\n` denotes a Windows line break (Carriage Return and Newline). If you're working with other line endings you might only need to look for `\n`.

Comment: can you explain that further 'cos when you say `"Search and Replace with the extended replace for \r\n and replace it with \r\n "`   It sounds like replacing `\r\n` with `\r\n`` which would do nothing.. you say "extended replace" what is that. And how is replacnig with the same thing you search for going to do anythnig?

Comment: It's not replacing with the same thing. It's replacing `\r\n` with `\r\n <plus your desired text>`. (The "and your text" part of the comment is easy to miss.) As for "Extended Replace", there is an "Extended" checkbox in the `Replace` dialog of Notepad++. You need to check that box to enable the `\r` and `\n` functionality.

Comment: @barlop maybe that makes it clearer. Otherwise it's as the other comment pointed out. if you're curious about the search and replace dialog for Notepad++ have a look at [this question and my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1234115/how-to-add-new-line-before-msh-in-notepadd-the-represent-any-numer-t/1234129#1234129). If you open it, it's pretty obvious what I mean by extended. Thanks for your feedback regardless!

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way to do this is via a macro

1. Put your `taskkill /f /im ffs.exe notepad.exe one.txt` onto the
   clip board.
2. Go to the end of the first line in your document and
   hit record
3. Press carriage return/enter, then ctrl+v
4. Cursor down to the end of the next numerical value
5. Stop recording
6. Now click Play to end of file